# Calculus of $\phi(x)=\lim_{\beta\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}g(x)] dx}{\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}] dx}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, expected-value

Let $f$, $g$ be two continuous function.

I want to calculate
$$
\phi(x)=\lim_{\beta\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}g(x)] dx}{\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}] dx}.
$$

If $f\equiv g$, I know the value of the limit is $\max_{x\in[-1,1]}f(x).$

What if $f\neq g$? Is the answer $$\max\{g(x): x\in\arg\max f(x)\}$$
right?

For example, Let $f(x)= xy$, and $g(x)\equiv y$ for some $y\in \mathbb{R}$. In this case, the value is 1, which equals $\max\{g(x): x\in\arg\max f(x)\}$.

What if $x$ becomes a vector, $f$ becomes $f: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $g$ becomes $g: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$? Would the answer be
$$
(\phi(x))_i=\max\{g_i(x): x\in\arg\max f(x)\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,n?
$$

Furthermore, which one of the following is bigger with a large $\beta$,
$$
 \frac{\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}f(x)] dx}{\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}] dx}, \text{ and } \log\left(\int_{x\in[-1,1]}[e^{\beta f(x)}] dx\right)/\beta.
$$

Comment: The "expectation" is not well defined unless you provide the distribution (for example, through a density).